# Upload css to pages with different id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flask, flask-restful

I am working on flask REST web project that have to serve different rooms by their id's.

Here an issue: project files like images, static files, can't upload to page with id. But perfectly uploads to static pages. What is the reason? Should I do something on client side?

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/room')
@app.route('/room/<int:id_room>')
@Auth.login_required
def room(id_room=None):
    return render_template(('room/room.html'), id_room=id_room)
```

Room it is only a static html page, but in future I want to place chats in different rooms.
For requests from client side I have an endpoints file.

Comment: Do you have some error message when you try to run your code? Please include it to your question. Or fact that it doesn't give any errors. And with Flask you might find useful information in logs. The more relevant information you give the better answers you'll get.

Comment: What do you mean by "upload"? If "load", then most likely you're using relative URLs. But anyway it's impossible to detect unless you show us a code where CSS and JS dependencies are being referred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `href` on the HTML page.
I've needed to provide a relative path.
Which directory structure I had:

static
|_room.css
templates
|_room
-- |_room.html

So in the "room" directory, I've should write a link to CSS like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../room.css">
```

Consider adding a `../` before link to source to get files that placed in upper directory tree.